I got an error in my creating React folder in my vs-code
npm error syscall lstat
npm error path C:\Users\Ganesh\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Ganesh\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Ganesh\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-08T07_20_06_250Z-debug-0.log

how could i solve this problem?

What's your version of npm?
